# how to get all videos in photos library using PHAsset

Tags: phasset, photosframework, photokit, phassetcollection

how to get all videos in photos library using PHAsset.

```
NSArray* selectedMediaTypes = @[@(PHAssetMediaTypeImage)];
    options.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType in %@", selectedMediaTypes];
    options.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO]];
    PHFetchResult *assetsFetchResult = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithOptions:options];
```

but It misses some videos that lies under this category `PHAssetCollectionSubtypeSmartAlbumsynched`

So how can I get all my videos in my photos library whether it is slowmo or synched or normal.